# Top Placeholder content renders underneath nav bar for small screen sizes

Tags: spfx, office-ui-fabric-react, applicationcustomizers

In my Sharepoint Online tenant, I have an Application Customizer that I am using to render a React component in the Top Placeholder.  The Application Customizer renders on top of the Nav bar using a high z-index and absolute positioning.

This works well for viewport sizes above 1023px; however, for an screen size smaller than 1023px the Application Customizer renders underneath the Nav bar, despite maintaining a high z-index.

Is it possible to have an Application Customizer display on top of the Nav bar at lower screen sizes?  Or is this a limitation of Placeholders?

React Component

```
import * as React from "react";
import { FunctionComponent } from "react";
import {  SearchBox } from "office-ui-fabric-react";
import { INavBarSearchProps } from "./INavBarSearchProps";

const NavBarSearch: FunctionComponent<INavBarSearchProps> = (
  props: INavBarSearchProps
) => {
  return (
      <SearchBox
        className={styles.searchBox}
        placeholder="Search for a person, practice, topic or keyword..."
        onChange={(e) => console.log(`onChange`,e.target.value)}
        onSubmit={(e) => console.log(`onSubmit`,e)}
      />
  );
};

export default NavBarSearch;
```

Styles

```
  .searchBox {
  width: 35%;
  max-width: 480px;
  height: 35px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -3.25%;
  left: 30%;
  z-index: 9999;
  border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI figured it out.  Seems like Sharepoint wanted the position to be `fixed` and not `absolute` in the media queries.